# select the emails releated with id i am usin laravel 8

Tags: php, sql, laravel

the request array has many user id i want to select all the emails related with these ids

but the result show me the email of first id an request array

```
 public function ActionUserPush(Request $request)
    {

        $data = $request->user_id;

        $value =  DB::table('users')->where('id', $data)->pluck('email');
        dd($value);
}
```

Comment: If the request has many user IDs in an array, you need `whereIn` instead of `where`.

Comment: What is the value of  dd($request->user_id);

Answer (score 0):

user id shoud be an array , so

```
 $value =  DB::table('users')->whereIn('id', $data)->pluck('email');
```